# What's the "textbook" way to write a passive sentence with a phrasal verb?

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs, passive-voice

So, I understand that the prohibition against ending a sentence with a preposition was only ever a myth, and isn't a rule we need to follow.

Still, it was a rule I was taught in school, so presumably people who follow this rule have some way of dealing with it.

But I cannot imagine how to rewrite a sentence like,

> If you do that, you might get yelled at.

Because

> If you do that, at you might get yelled.

is nonsensical ("at you" isn't a noun, so can't "get" anything).

Can it be done?

Comment: "... a yell might be directed at you." "... a yell might be emitted in your direction." "... there might be a yell [at you]."

Comment: A silly new rule up you must make.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would replace "yelled at" with "reprimanded".  For example, "If you do that, you might get reprimanded".  If the word "reprimanded" is too ambiguous for that context, I would use "verbally reprimanded".

Comment: I think this is a more general question. (So, it seems like your answer is "there is no general answer, you have to reword.")